# Kubuntu 17.10 Mobile Broadband Problem

Tags: kubuntu, mobile-broadband

I'm having issues with mobile broadband.

- I use the 4.13.16 generic kernel because the latest 4.14 kernels break my virtual machine kernel modules. Not sure if this matters as info.
- The Mobile Broadband Modem is **Dell Wireless 5630 EVDO-HSPA Mobile Broadband Mini-Card Modem**
- Mobile Broadband worked in Kubuntu 16.04, 16.10, and 17.04. Never worked in 17.10 for me.
- The Mobile Broadband shows up in my network manager list of connections, just refuses to connect. It gets stuck on "Preparing to connect" then fails and never does anything until a reboot or restart of the network service. (Yes, the connection is set up properly)

I know I've read of someone downgrading to an older modem manager and it works again... **but how?**

Is there another way to fix this or is the downgrade the only way to go about it at this moment? If so, please give me the terminal commands to downgrade because I can't figure this out.

I know 17.10 is unstable and not all that great for production.. but I've been using this release and running it to the ground with absolutely no problems except this hiccup.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

***EDIT***

Thank you, **MichaelBay**

I have a **Dell Wireless 5630 EVDO-HSPA Mobile Broadband Mini-Card Modem**

**LSUSB only puts out**:

> Bus 002 Device 003: ID 413c:8194 Dell Computer Corp.
>
> Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching
>   Hub
>
> Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>
> Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0eef:0001 D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd eGalax
>   TouchScreen
>
> Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0d8c:013c C-Media Electronics, Inc. CM108 Audio
>   Controller
>
> Bus 001 Device 010: ID 04a9:176d Canon, Inc. PIXMA MG2550
>
> Bus 001 Device 009: ID 1c4f:0054 SiGma Micro
>
> Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1a2c:2d43 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd
>
> Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
>
> Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
>
> Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching
>   Hub
>
> Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>
> Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
>
> Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Since this is not a USB dongle, I do not think it will show up in that. My apologies for forgetting that key info.

**EDIT #2**

Okay, so, I have attempted the downgrade with no success. There are incompatible dependencies. Tried the command line way, tried synaptics way, tried the compiled package and binary way. No go.

So there has to be another way to make this work.. Maybe a tweak? Do I need to edit some source code and recompile?

Comment: Please post the exact hardware you're using (modem). You can use `lsusb` to find out, assuming it's a regular USB dongle. Always [edit] your question to add new information.

Comment: Thank you, MichaelBay, I added the recommended information.